# Как слинковать MinGW либу с MSVC проектом, имея def-файлы?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, ffmpeg, mingw

Пытаюсь под Windows слинковать FFmpeg с проектом (через `extern "C"`). С MinGW 8.1.0 в тестовом проекте получилось успешно слинковать, с MSVC - ошибка. Пробема в том, что в проекте я использую STL Filesystem, которой вроде как нет в MinGW, по крайней мере я не могу с ней скомпилировать. Я использую CMake, и через него установлен 17й стандарт, так что дело не в нём.

В скачанной [отсюда](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) dev-сборке, есть def-файлы, которые вроде как должны разрешить эту проблему, или нет? Ещё нашёл [такое](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-September/016529.html), что каким-то образом через `target_set_properties()` задают флаги и ссылаются на эти def-файлы. Но в данном случае таргета не создётся.

Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему? Большое спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"использую STL Filesystem, которой вроде как нет в MinGW"* Он там есть, уже довольно давно. Скажите версию MinGW, флаги, и ошибки, которые получили.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, 8.1.0

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, обшибки в духе:
```C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\bits\fs_path.h:237: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~```

Comment: Попробуйте MinGW поновее. Из MSYS2 можно скачать GCC 10.1.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, для поновее нет комплекта в Qt. Проект на Qt

Comment: С qt-creator'ом не работал. Без этого "комплекта" никак? Должно быть можно просто указать путь к компилятору.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, никак, дело в том, что я использую не просто IDE, я использую фреймворк Qt с его классами и модулями, типа Core, Gui, Widgets...

Comment: Ладно, вот вам другой, более простой вариант: удалите свои qt и qt-creator, скачайте MSYS2 и поставьте оттуда не только GCC, но и сам qt и qt-creator. Смотрите [здесь](https://wiki.qt.io/MSYS2) раздел `Obtain Pre-Built Qt & QtCreator ...`. Должно сработать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, дело в том, что GCC должен поддерживать Filesystem, начиная с 8.0 (но это не точно). А вообще вариант так себе. Вот здесь написано https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support  в  разделе C++17 library features.

Comment: Судя по [этому](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/737/), у вас filesystem не работает из-за бага 8-ого GCC (баг специфичный для винды, видимо поэтому на cppreference не упоминается). У меня стоит 10-ый gcc из msys2, и здесь filesystem работает. На 9-ом кажется тоже работала. *"А вообще вариант так себе."* Почему?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, потому что это создаст новые проблемы рано или поздно и потребует кучу времени для того, чтобы понять как всё это работает. Видимо должен быть вариант проще. Не зря там лежат .def-файлы. Но я в этом не уверен. В общем, гораздо лучше научиться под Windows линковать FFmpeg с MSVC.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, или самому собрать FFmpeg с помощью MSVC...

Comment: Ну, мое дело предложить. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Приведите ваш `CMakeLists.txt`, если собираете с помощью `CMake`. *с MSVC - ошибка* - какая ошибка? В общем, нужен [mcve].

Comment: @Tocic, ошибка линковки MinGW-либы (FFmpeg) и MSVC-проекта. При этом есть готовая сборка с def-файлами. Нужно только понять как сделать с их помощью lib-файлы, которые можно слинковать с MSVC. В CMakeLists.txt ошибок нет, и показывать там нечего.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы получилось, слинквалось, ошибки нет. Вот что я сделал:

1. В `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\`**{Hostx64\x64|Hostx32\x32}**
   лежит файл `lib.exe`. Его нужно добавить в переменную окружения
   `Path`, чтобы можно было запускать как команду из консоли (хотя
   можете просто прописать путь целиком при вызове).
2. И выполнить что-то
   типа: `lib /machine:x64 /def:your_lib.def` или `lib /machine:x32 /def:your_lib.def`, после чего выведет сообщение:
   `Creating library your_lib.lib and object your_lib.exp`.